# Find the length of $BC$.

Tags: geometry

[image]

For a circle centered at $O$, line $L$ is tangent to the circle at $A$ and has slope $-1/2$. If $AB$ is perpendicular to $OC$ and $OB$ has length $2$, then what is the length of $BC$?

Comment: $8$ ${{{{{}}}}}$

Answer (score 2):

Let corner angle at $ C = \alpha$
$$ \tan \alpha = \frac12;\, BC = x ;\, AC= x \sec \alpha $$
By a standard property of right angled triangles,
$$ (x \sec \alpha)^2 = x (x +2) $$
simplify

$$ x = BC = \frac {2}{{\tan^2 \alpha}} = 8.  $$

The sketch is not proportionately drawn.Also

$$ AB =4, AC = 4 \sqrt 5 $$

Answer (score 2):

This is a sneaky problem! Here's my illustration:
[image: Circle-Line]

We were told $\overline{A B}$ is perpendicular to $\overline{O C}$. Therefore, $\angle OBA = \angle ABC = 90°$.

Because line $L$ is tangent to the circle at $A$, and $O$ is the center of the circle, $\angle OAC$ is $90°$.

Because triangles $\triangle OAC$ and $\triangle OAB$ are similar (being right triangles and sharing two vertices and so on), we know that $\varphi = \angle OCA = \angle BAO$, and that
 $$\frac{OA}{OB} = \frac{OC}{OA} \implies OC = OA \frac{OA}{OB}$$
and therefore
$$BC = OC - OB = OA \frac{OA}{OB} - OB = \frac{(OA)^2 - (OB)^2}{OB}$$
Since
$$\sin \varphi = \frac{OB}{OA} \implies OA = \frac{OB}{\sin \varphi}$$
we know that
$$BC = \frac{\left(\frac{OB}{\sin\varphi}\right)^2 - \left(OB\right)^2}{OB} = \frac{OB \; (\cos\varphi)^2}{(\sin\varphi)^2} = \frac{OB}{(\tan\varphi)^2}$$

Here we come to the sneaky part. *The slope of $L$ does not matter*, because we were not given any information on the orientation of the other elements!

If we assume that "the slope of $L$ is $-1/2$" is meant as *with respect to* $\overline{OC}$ -- or, equivalently, that $\overline{OC}$ is parallel to the $x$-axis --, then $\tan \varphi = \lvert -1/2 \rvert = 1/2$, and
$$BC = \frac{OB}{(\tan\varphi)^2} = \frac{2}{1/4} = 8$$
which matches what [Nikunj](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/287774/nikunj) commented and [Narasimhan](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1722917/318422) answered before me.

Personally, I'm uncomfortable with making such an assumption (based on an unreliable figure, and just to provide *an* answer), but then again, I'm an ornery fellow anyway.

Comment: OBC is on x-axis. Implicit in OP's indication is that tangent L's slope is $ -\frac12. $

Comment: @Narasimham: I do gently disagree. Line $L$'s slope fixes the slope of $OA$ (since the two are perpendicular), but I see nowhere a reason to assume $C$ has the same $y$-coordinate as $O$. We could, for example, fix the original figure by rotating it slightly counterclockwise, so that the slope of $L$ in it was $-1/2$. Why would that be incorrect? Is rotating the figure somehow less correct than modifying it altogether?

Comment: Dont you see the OP is a newbie it is not that much worthy of attention, with due awareness of a guru. ..Can I suggest forget it,  I shall post big problem with bounties if you have time and the inclination

Comment: @Narasimham:  I'm not a mathematician, I'm a physicist. All assumptions, even those necessary to find an answer, are important and must be recognized, or the model fails. Mathematicians seem to think that if an assumption is necessary to find an answer, and the answer satisfies the problem, it suffices; yet, such an answer only exists if the assumptions are true. In physics, finding a question that has no answer is likely more important than any single answer made with additional assumptions. Here, the question should have stated $BC = 2AB$ for clarity. Badly stated problems are bad problems.

Answer (score 1):

From Euclid we know that $2\cdot BC=(AB)^2$, on the other hand we know that $2AB=BC$, hence $ BC=8$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\theta$ be the angle between $L$ and OC. We have the following equations:
$$\tan(\theta) = \frac{|OA|}{|AC|}=\frac{2}{|AB|},$$
and
$$\frac{|AB|}{|BC|}=\frac{1}{2}=\tan(\theta).$$
Since $\tan(\pi-\theta) = -\tan(\theta)$, we get that $|AB| = 4$ and $|BC| = 8$.